# Why is this version of OpenSSL (1.0.1e) not vulnerable to Heartbleed?

Tags: tls, exploit, openssl, heartbleed

I recently ran into a requirement that needed a web server set up with SSL, to show that its possible to extract the private key from a server with a vulnerable version of OpenSSL (**Heartbleed**). Hence, I downloaded a version of Debian I knew that shipped with the vulnerable version of OpenSSL from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/7.4.0/amd64/jigdo-dvd/).

However after configuring it, it wasn't leaking anything (as reported by Metasploit).

Below is the output from `openssl version -a`:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Sat Jun 13 10:26:40 UTC 2015
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

From what I know, versions between *1.0.1* through to *1.0.1f* are vulnerable. I can see that it was built on a later date. My questions are:

1. Which compile option made it safe against Heartbleed? I don't see `DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS flag` option in the output above.
2. Where can I get a Debian version (7 or later) which actually ships with the vulnerable version of OpenSSL needed to demo Heartbleed.

Comment: They might have backported the patch.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by @void_in, they backported the patch. Check your package version like so:

```
dpkg -l openssl
```

From 1.0.1e-2+deb7u5, the security patch has been [included](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1e-2+deb7u17_changelog).:

> openssl (1.0.1e-2+deb7u5) wheezy-security; urgency=high
>
> - Non-maintainer upload by the Security Team.
> - Add
>     CVE-2014-0160.patch patch.
>     CVE-2014-0160: Fix TLS/DTLS hearbeat information disclosure.
>     A missing bounds check in the handling of the TLS heartbeat extension
>     can be used to reveal up to 64k of memory to a connected client or
>     server.

The files relating to 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4 can be found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/debian/wheezy/openssl/wheezy/files/53), and you should be able to [revert back to a previous version](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/wheezy/sect.apt-get.html) of a package by adding entries in the /etc/apt/preferences file.

Comment: My OpenSSL version (using an LTS distro) is `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` - why do they keep the "2014", it's irritating. Shouldn't this date info be updated to the the day of the latest patch?