# Help with creating Heartbleed vulnerable server

Tags: metasploit, virtualization, kali-linux, heartbleed

I am using Virtualbox internal network with Kali Linux and Ubuntu 12.04. The version of OpenSSL for the Ubuntu is 1.0.1 which should be vulnerable. I have created a HTTPS server using nginx on the Ubuntu and when i scan with nmap on the Kali Linux it shows that port 80 for http and port 443 for https is open. However, when i use the heartbleed exploit on Metasploit in Kali and run the check command it says:

```
[*] 192.168.1.70:443 The target is not exploitable
[*] Checked 1 of 1 hosts (100% complete)
```

Running nmap with

```
nmap -d –script ssl-heartbleed –script-args vulns.showall -sV 192.168.1.70
```

also does not give me anything.

How do I create a heartbleed-vulnerable server? I dont mind trying out another method as long as it works. The method here was done following https://warroom.securestate.com/building-a-vulnerable-box-heartbleed/

Comment: You can download vulnerable VMs with heartbleed present from vulnhub, if you are just wanting to practice exploiting it. This VM for example has it: https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/bwapp-bee-box-v16,53/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using a version of 12.04 which was unpatched for years the OpenSSL on your test server is not vulnerable even if the OpenSSL version number shows a vulnerable version. Vendors backport security fixes in the OpenSSL versions they ship and thus the version number itself does not say a lot. See [Why is this version of OpenSSL (1.0.1e) not vulnerable to Heartbleed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101404/why-is-this-version-of-openssl-1-0-1e-not-vulnerable-to-heartbleed)
.

Thus if you would like to setup a vulnerable system either get old and unpatched images or get the vulnerable version from [openssl.org](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/) and compile it yourself and also make sure that all applications you want to test are linked with this vulnerable version.